# Work with corine landcover raster

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.2

I am using Arcgis 10.2.2 and I need to extract the landcover variables, one by one, from one raster layer that have all the variables together. How can I do this?

And then, how do I joint this information with a vector shp with points? (For each point I need to know the value of the land cover variable).

Ok, and if I have buffers (a layer shp with buffers)? What I want is that for each one of my buffers, I will have the average for each one of the land cover characteristics.
buffer 1 - so I will have an average value/or a 0, for each one the characteristics 
buffer 2
...

Comment: Please elaborate why you want to split the raster. That's not necessary for extracting the raster value at vector point locations.

Comment: Well, I think that was the way... because I have 44 characteristics in one raster file. Can you help me?

Comment: Search toolbox\help file; there is a tool called extract values to points.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, this should be a fairly straightforward analysis, though there are a few ways you could approach it.

You could use the **Raster to Point tool in the Conversion toolbox**.
http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//001200000007000000

in_raster = [Your land cover dataset]
out_point_features = [Designate an output feature class]
raster_field = [The value field that holds land cover values in your dataset]

Then you have a "grid-looking" point feature class (may be a bit resource intensive depending on the size and spatial resolution of your land cover dataset) that you can then do a select by attribute or a SQL definition query on to limit the dataset to just the land cover values you want.

**Or,**

If you already have a point feature class that you want to use to grab values, and you have access to Spatial Analyst, use **Extract Values to Points in the Spatial Analyst toolbox**.
http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//009z0000002t000000

in_point_features = [Your pre-made point feature class]
in_raster = [Land cover dataset]
out_point_features = [Designate an output point feature class]
optional fields: Should be able to ignore these unless your needs dictate otherwise.

Again after you get the output you could use a select by attributes or SQL definition query to pull out only the values you want.

Conversely if, for some reason, you need to limit the land cover values before you extract them, you could use the Con tool in Spatial Analyst to return the values you need, then use one of the above methods.
http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//009z00000005000000

Hopefully one of those two solutions helps.

Comment: +1 Extract Values to Points.  I would advise against using Raster to Point as this operation is computationally expensive and there is almost always a more efficient raster-based approach.